# Localization in Fluent UI

Tags: i18next, office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am trying to implement localization in react app using i18next and Fluent UI.

As seen here - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/styles/web/localization

The docs day "Fluent UI supports a variety of language codes, which map to the following font stacks: .."

How to set the 'language code' in Fluent UI to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 1):

Late reply, but I was looking into the same thing. Looks like Fluent automatically adjusts a bunch of things based on your browser settings.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/173424?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop

You can customize the language in code using

```
<html lang="th-TH">
```